# Unresolved reference error is showing up after adding the dgs codegen plugin successfully

Tags: spring-boot, gradle-kotlin-dsl, netflix-dgs

I am trying to use DGS Codegen plugin in my spring boot GQL project,

Here is the build.gradle.kts file, where the respective dependencies mentioned

```kotlin
plugins {
    java
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "3.2.4"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.1.4"
    id("com.netflix.dgs.codegen") version "6.1.5"
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom("com.netflix.graphql.dgs:graphql-dgs-platform-dependencies:latest.release")
    }
}
```

The plugin generates the code as expected from the schema file, However I am still seeing the unresolved reference error for each 3 lines in the given script as below,

```kotlin
tasks.generateJava {
    schemaPaths.add("${projectDir}/src/main/resources/schema") // List of directories containing schema files
    packageName = "com.example.dgsdemo" // The package name to use to generate sources
    generateClient = true // Enable generating the type safe query API
}
```

[Error screen shot]
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/LCj73.png)

Do we need to check any other config settings, to make sure if the plugin is imported properly?
Any suggestions to debug more?

**Tried options:**

- Upgraded to the latest package
- Invalidated cache and restarted intellij
- Tried to clean before the gradle build